# Drupal slideshow of images belonging to same node

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm making a website in drupal 7 and need some help.

I created a content type called Itenary where user will upload information and five images.
The images I have taken as Image1, Image2.... Image5 as fields of type image pf the itenary content type.

Now I wish to show these images as simple slideshow of the node that is currently being seen

So I go to the views module -> add new view
Now when I had tried this before, I had selected

> Show *content* of type *itenary*

And it didn't work as I hoped.

So this time, I chose

> Show *File* of type *Image*

I hope this is the right option for my need.
Then I went to create a block, gave it a name.

Now my dilema is how do I bring those fields of Image1 Image2 .. Image5 into this block ?
The fields it shows by default are related to files and not the field of my content type.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach to display images in a slideshow: [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/).